# How to diplay points on drawn linestring in openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I use the Editing-Toolbar of OpenLayers on a simple map. Everything works fine so far, I can draw points, lines and polygons.

I have the following result by drawing a simple linestring on the given map:

[OpenLayers Example 1](http://www.imagebanana.com/view/j4jzbhw7/Selection_001.png)

What I actually want is, that OpenLayers automatically adds the points to the linestring like so:

[OpenLayers Example 2](http://www.imagebanana.com/view/0d0x9ip6/Selection_002.png)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a function that will be fired on end of drawing Function will loop over each vertex of newly created line and create a points (in the new layer, I suggest). Do you want to save it somewhere?

```
map.layers[1].events.register('sketchcomplete', this, extractVertex);

//f is an object sketched
function extractVertex(f) {

    var arrayOfPointsInWKT = [];
    var vert = f.feature.geometry.getVertices();
    for(var i = 0; i < vert.length; i++) {
        arrayOfPointsInWKT.push(vert[i].toString());
    }

    //ajax call to the script that will save a table it in the database

}
```

Comment: Yes, after creating the desired geometry the coordinates of all points and lines shall be saved in a database. How can I fire a point draw function after drawing a line?

Comment: see edits. map.layers[1] must be replaced with your vector layer. I save to database sending coordinates as WKT strings to php script and then in SQL: ST_GeomFromText(my_wkt_string)

Answer (score -1):

You should look at the documentation of feature styling (StyleMaps, Rulebased styling etc) that you can find [here](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html). It will give you what you need.

**EDIT**

As I recalled it, points were a part of LineStrings, it seems I was wrong... I see now that it was the points you were looking for, more than the styling of them. Sorry for the misplaced answer.

I found a post on the GIS site which looks like something you could use. Good luck!

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28242/show-a-collection-of-linestrings-with-labels

Comment: I will check the solution on this site and post my experience soon